# Need to put a border color when a menu link is :hover, but it has to be over an hr

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a psd template for doing a website and I'm developing it with bootstrap, trying to make it responsive.

I want to obtain this effect:

http://pho.to/9RxrT (It's a link to a photo. StackOverflow doesn't allowed me to upload a photo.)

I managed to obtain it, but only for a few screen width, when I resize the screen it changes completally.

I have this CSS:

```css
.menu {
    width: auto;
    font: 400 24px Calibri;
}

.vcenter {
    padding: 5% 0 1%;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #7d2828 !important;
    border-bottom: 3px #7d2828 solid;
    padding-bottom: 96px;
}

a,a:active,a.active,a:visited,a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #444443;
}

header hr {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #a5a5a5;
}
```

And this block of my HTML document:

```css
       <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row vcenter">
                    <div class="logo col-sm-2 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logotipo" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-md-offset-1 col-md-8 vcenter">
                        <ul class="menu text-uppercase list-inline pull-right">
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </header>
```

I found it out, that for a padding of 96px it fixs over the hr. But I dont know how to do it dinamically. I have tried to use @media queries, without success.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that abuts the bottom of the list with `<hr>` element so for that you have to remove the `border-bottom` of the list and the `border-top` of `hr` and in your example you have to change the

```
.vcenter {
    padding: 5% 0 1%;
}
```

by

```
.vcenter {
    padding: 5% 0 0;
}
```

once adjoin the elements, you have to overlap the bottom of the list with the `hr`

doing this:

```
menu{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

and now you have to make `li` and `a` elemtents get to the bottom of the list

```
li, a{
    height: 100%
}

a{
    display:inline-block; /*block works too, the catch is changes the `display:inline`
}
```

and here you have it, now you only have to put the desired size `menu`

like `height: 96px`

here you have a fiddle example with 2 menus at different size and both working

i remove some of your code to clarify

http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/35ft5t4k/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? You need to define a minimum width on the menu container to keep the menu items on the same line.

```css
.menu {
    width: auto;
    font: 400 24px Calibri;
}

.vcenter {
    padding: 5% 0 1%;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #7d2828 !important;
    border-bottom: 3px #7d2828 solid;
}

a,a:active,a.active,a:visited,a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #444443;
}

ul.menu {
    min-width: 25em;
    border-bottom: 3px #a5a5a5 solid;
}

ul.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
       <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row vcenter">
                    <div class="logo col-sm-2 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logotipo" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-md-offset-1 col-md-8 vcenter">
                        <ul class="menu text-uppercase list-inline pull-right">
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, it's usefull too. But It's not what I'm looking for. I want the bottom red border to stay over the separator (hr) all the time (for all the screen width) when the link is :hover, like in this photo  ( http://pho.to/9RxrT ).

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and your time Bottstein.